# Melhor forma de realizar Injeção de dependência no Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, injeção-de-dependência

Estou trabalhando em um sistema bastante grande onde estou criando diversos módulos e precisava orientá-los de forma coerente. Atualmente estou centralizando a injeção de dependência em um único módulo, o que eu acredito não ser o correto, pois a ideia de módulo é ser interindependente. Vocês teriam alguma ideia de como posso orientá-los corretamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Costumo separar meu módulos por features, em cada feature coloco suas dependências e depois disso coloco a feature como dependência do módulo principal.
Uma sugestão é dar uma olhada no styleguide do Jhon Papa:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y165

Esse item em especifico fala um pouco sobre dependências.

Answer (score 2):

O que eu costumo fazer, já que são módulos, ou seja, vou utilizar um módulo somente em uma determinada área da minha aplicação, é utilizar o módulo [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad). Ele proporciona o carregamento dos meus módulos (ou dos módulos que eu julgar necessário) somente na view (ou state) que me interessar.

**Prós:**

- Aplicação fica mais leve, já que o módulo só é carregado em determinada view.
- Segurança, pelo mesmo motivo anterior. Ele só é carregado se o usuário acessar a view.

**Contras:**

- Se for uma aplicação pequena, ou não complexa, pode aumentar ainda mais o trabalho, ao invés de ajudar.
- Você precisa ter um controle/manutenção mais bem organizado, ou pode se perder fácil no código.

O site do módulo possui uma excelente documentação, mas vou explicar como eu uso. Como utilizo `ui-router` nos meus projetos, eu aplico o uso do `oc.lazyload` diretamente no `resolve` dentro das configurações de `state`, deste modo:

```
.state('inicio', {
    url:'/BemVindo',
    resolve: {
        loadMyCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                names: 'meuModulo',
                files: 'app/modulo/meumodulo.js'
            });
        }]
    }
})
```

Lembrando que, utilizando esta ferramenta você não vai mais precisar declarar o módulo `meuModulo` (por exemplo) no seu módulo principal:

```
angular.module('mainApp', [
    'meuModulo' //Não é mais necessário isso
]);
```

A ferramenta `oc.lazyload` irá se encarregar de fazer tanto o carregamento do arquivo físico (meumodulo.js) como da injeção dinâmica do módulo para uso. O bom desta ferramenta, também é a 'não' dependência de fazer o load somente no router. Existem outras formas de se fazer isso, como por exemplo, através de um directive:

```
<div oc-lazy-load="['meumodulo.js']">
    //.. restante do conteudo
</div>
```

Obs.: O `oc.lazyload` não é o único método de se obter este resultado, existem outras ferramentas que também podem fazer isso, como [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/). Este é apenas o meu método de utilizar.

Apenas atente-se para a nomenclatura dos seus módulos, não use algo muito breve, como `mdNot`, use algo mais intuitivo como `mdNoticias`.

Outras dicas melhores, acompanhe o link disponibilizado na outra resposta. O guia do [John](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y165) é realmente uma excelente fonte!